# Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal. Htaccess error

Tags: .htaccess

my apache error log is full of this, I don't know what is wrong. This is my .htaccess file. Can somebody help me?

```
RewriteEngine on
# check that the request url is neither a file nor a directory

RewriteRule    ^panel/?$    panel/  [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    app.php?slug=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/index/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    app.php?slug=$1&index=$2    [NC,L] 

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|bmp) /images/default.jpg [NC,L]
```

and I have another subdomain who redirects to this. And htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ro.sughy.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|bmp) /images/default.jpg [NC,L]
```

Comment: Do you have any other rules in the htaccess?

Comment: No, this is a subdomain, and I have another subdomain who is redirected to this. This is redirected subdomain htaccess:  RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ro.sughy.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|bmp) /images/default.jpg [NC,L]

Comment: I found, I have AWS CloudFront, and images are temporary, and If someone acces the image after is deleted I get this error. Can you help me to fix it? Thank you!